# How to remove unmet dependecies Debian 7 Wheezy

Tags: apt, debian, dependencies

I'm trying to install different packages but it's showing unmet dependencies in most of them even after `sudo apt-get -f install`.
Below is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# 

# deb-src cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.1.0 _Wheezy_ - Official Multi-architecture i386/amd64/source DVD #1 20130615-23:45]/ wheezy main
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.1.0 _Wheezy_ - Official Multi-architecture i386/amd64/source DVD #1 20130615-23:45]/ wheezy main
# 

#deb-src cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.1.0 _Wheezy_ - Official Multi-architecture i386/amd64/source DVD #1 20130615-23:45]/ wheezy main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.1.0 _Wheezy_ - Official Multi-architecture i386/amd64/source DVD #1 20130615-23:45]/ wheezy main
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
##################
## Debian Stable  ##
##################
# Stable
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
# Stable Sources
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

# Security Updates  http://www.debian.org/security/
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed `wheezy` and  `squeeze` entires in your `sources.list`. They can be used together, but you should properly setup pinning.

Most likely you should just change squeeze(oldstable) to wheezy(current stable) and upgrade whole system to stable, documentation on upgrade can be found [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html)